# Arbitrum and Ethereum Interoperability

Tags: layer-2, arbitrum

I have a contract deployed on Ethereum that have a public view that returns one data
i need that data on a contract on Arbitrum

I have seen the documentation of arbitrum and I have seen that it is possible through arbsys to send transactions from L2 to L1, but how will the results of the function get back to me?

calling the arbsys function on L2

```
function sendTxToL1 (address destination, bytes calldata calldataForL1) external payable returns (uint);
```

I send the transaction on L1, but it only returns me an id of the sent transaction, not the result of the transaction